# How to create a column that has the counts of specific instances that meet certain conditions?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of news that has a column with all the headlines of articles written throughout the year; another column with the month of the article; and a column that classifies the articles as positive, negative, balanced or informational.

The dataframe looks like this (here with made-up examples for only January and March):

```
Headline                    month          tendency
'The US Economy xxxxxx'     January        positive
'The UN warns xxxxxxxx'     January        balanced
'Tesla xxxxxxxx'            March          positive
```

The data covers all months and I would like to create a column named count that has the number of articles that were published in a specific month and are positive, negative, balanced or informational. For example, say January has 40 articles in total, of those, 20 were positive, 5 were balanced, 5 were informational, and 10 were negative. For March you have 30 articles in total, 15 positive, 5 negative, 5 balanced and 5 informational. In the column that I want to create the value will be the number previously stated depending on the tendency of the article. So the final data frame would look like this:

```
Headline                    month          tendency     count
'The US Economy xxxxxx'     January        positive     20
'The UN warns xxxxxxxx'     January        balanced     5
'Tesla xxxxxx'              March          positive     15
```

It doesn't matter that the value of count gets repeated, I just need it for reference.

I was able to print the results and the logic is working really well but I'm not able to figure out a way to create the column and assigning the values for each month.

The code that I have looks like this:

```
data[(data[month] == 'January') & (data['tendency'] == 'Positive')].count()
```

You can change the month and tendency and it will give you the desired result. Should I write an if statement for every month an every tendency? What would be the best way to create the count column?

Comment: It looks like your resulting table has headlines too.  From your explanation, it sounds like you just want month/tendency/count in the result (since you're counting individual articles).  Have I misunderstood?

Comment: Hi Joshua @JoshuaR. ! Yes, the table has headlines too. Let me try to rephrase the goal. The column I want has all the counts for the positive, negative, balanced, and informational articles that were published for each month. I didn't mention the headlines since I'm not taking them into consideration for the calculation (I don't have duplicates). I have seen solutions that give you the count for all the instances in a particular column (that would mean all the positive results for all year), but the issue I have is that I want to make a distinction for every month.

Comment: ```df.groupby(['month', 'tendency']).size()``` should do what you want. It just doenst have the article name, but that seems to be okay based on what you stated.

Comment: Thank you so much :)  Ben @BenPap !

Comment: No problem! @AlonsoAg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you can do this with a combination of an aggregation/[groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and a [join](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html)

e.g. something like this:

```
# This is input, named 'df', I added a fourth headline to test the aggregation.
df = pd.DataFrame({'Headline' : ['The US Economy xxxxxx','The UN warns xxxxxxxx','Tesla xxxxxxxx','Tesla yyyyyyy'],
                      'month' : ['January','January','March','March'],
                   'tendency' : ['positive', 'balanced', 'positive', 'positive']})

# Make a series that counts articles by month and tendency
countByMonthTendency = df.groupby(['month','tendency']).size().rename('count')

# Join it back to your data on the same two columns.
df.join(countByMonthTendency, on=['month','tendency'])
```

which yields:

```
    Headline                month    tendency   count
0   The US Economy xxxxxx   January  positive   1
1   The UN warns xxxxxxxx   January  balanced   1
2   Tesla xxxxxxxx          March    positive   2
3   Tesla yyyyyyy           March    positive   2
```